# MySQL select with min

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to select fields `message` and `username` from table list where `list_id`=1 (it can be 2 or 5 etc) with minimal number value (min(`number`)). How can i do it?
I tried it:

```
SELECT `message`,`username` FROM `list` WHERE `list_id`=2 AND min(`number`)
```

But it not work.

Comment: Look at ordering and limiting. Order by `number` and limit to 1 is probably what you are looking for. `MIN` is an aggregate function which will be used with things like `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try so

```
SELECT `message`,`username`
FROM `list`
WHERE `list_id` = 2
ORDER BY `number` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity, except I'm not sure if the OP always expects only one record to match the criteria...

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `number` ASC LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: One shouldn't need to quote `number`, because it isn't a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html); not sure why @valera5505 was seeing a syntax error though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM list
INNER JOIN   (
     SELECT 
          `message`,
          `username`,
          MIN(`number`) 
     FROM `list` 
     WHERE `list_id`=2 
    ) as a on a.id = list.id
```

Comment: Is that valid without a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @PinnyM MySQL does not require a `GROUP BY` clause. However if it is not included the results can be unusual

Comment: Does it then infer a GROUP BY?  In that case, this won't do what the OP needs.

Comment: this is valid for getting the record with min value.

Comment: The join criteria refers to `a.id`, which doesn't exist?  Furthermore, the select list only selects columns from `a` so why join with `list` at all: why not just use the subquery alone?  However, as @PinnyM says, it won't do what the OP needs.

Comment: i have used id as conjunction you can use anything else. I have used join because the derieved query selects the record with minimun value. because if there are multiple records with min values it will select the one we want